# animate.css effects only when your screen sees the element ID

Tags: html, css, class, animate.css

Hi I was messing around with some CSS animation and found that animate.css which can be found here: http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ is really helpful. This css file is simple to use just adding the class animation followed by the effect you wish the element to have. Only thing I don't know how to do is trigger the effect only when the screen is on top of a certain #id or .class instead of the effect just loading when the page loads. Any idea?

Quick Example: ( Make the blue box animate the way it does but only when you scroll on top of it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
<style type="text/css">
body { width: 500px;}

.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background:#09F;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."<p/>
<p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."<p/>
<p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."<p/>
<p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."<p/>
<p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."<p/>
<div class="box animated rubberBand" id="box">Animation Box</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show some code, and possibily a fiddle...

Comment: I edited my question check it out

Answer (score 0):

I used this small JS code for adding class .fixed to element with class .top-menu when page scrolled from top for 50px. If u knew position of ur element u can add animation class when userscrolled from top u set.

```
<script>    
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var navigation = $('#header > .menu > .top-menu');
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 50)
        {
            if(!navigation.hasClass('fixed'))
            {
                navigation.addClass('fixed');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            navigation.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hmm only part I don't fully understand is the `var navigation = $('#header > .menu > .top-menu');` part. Is #header > .menu > .top-menu just the way you are selecting your menu as if you would in css?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the class name by capturing the position of the element and viewport.

that is

```
if( scroll down to the element ) {
  $('.target').addClass('active');
} else {
  $('.target').removeClass('active');
}
```

in your case, you can set the class to control the animation like this

```
$('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
```

UPDATE

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/mogaxoze/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: here is what I did in my html example assuming you already have animate.css linked [http://jsbin.com/citot/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output]

Comment: did this solve your problem? btw, you can decide the position you want to do the animation(add classes) by changing `scrolling > target - viewport / 2`

Comment: Yeah I got it to work by setting `viewport / 1`. I don't understand how `scrolling > target - viewport / 2` works tho?

Answer (score 0):

[Live Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/9Gxcu/2/)

For this you have use `bind` function from jquery

This function will add 'some-class-name-from-animated-css' when the particular section of html will display in user view.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){})
jQuery('.inview').bind('inview',function(event,visible)
{
    if(visible==true)
    {
        jQuery('.animated').addClass("some-class-name-from-animated-css");
    }
    else{
        jQuery('.animated').removeClass("some-class-name-from-animated-css");
    }
});
```

Your HTML will be:

```
<p id="test2" style="margin-bottom:900px">FOr Long Scroll Only</p>
<p id="test3" class="inview animated">Html Value</p>
```

On whatever section you need the page scroll animation you have to add this both classes `inview` and `animated`